# Open crystal report with subreport c# Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

While I'm using VS2010 to create crystal report, add a sub report, when I have link up 2 report by master table field. The crystal report in sub report will auto create the parameter field inside.

While I come back to vs2010, and write the below code

```
_Cnn.Open();
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, STUDENTNAME, AGE FROM CLASSMASTER", _Cnn);
SqlDataReader _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable _dt1 = new DataTable();
_dt1.Load(_reader);
_cmd = null;
_reader = null;

_cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT STUDENTID, NAMEBOO FROM LIBARYSRC", _Cnn);
_reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable _dt2 = new DataTable();
_dt2.Load(_reader);
ReportDocument _Report = new ReportDocument();
string _report = @"reports\classreport.rpt";
_Report.Load(_report);
_Report.SetDataSource(_dt1);
_Report.OpenSubreport("subreport").SetDataSource(_dt2);

crv.ReportSource = _Report; // crv is report viewer control
```

The report viewer always prompt for ask input value of that parameter field. But when I go to vs2010 report design to preview, it is no problem, how to prevent this prompt?

Thanks for your help.